# How to force decimal interpretation of printf's parameter in Bash instead of octal

Tags: bash, formatting, printf, decimal, octal

I am formatting numbers in a bash script with printf

```
printf "%04d" $input   # four digits width with leading zeros if shorter
```

If `input="011"` printf assumes the value is octal and returns `0009` instead of `0011`.

Is it possible to force printf to assume all values are decimal?

Comment: Why not just remove the leading zeroes when you assign to `input`?

Comment: In that case I have to check any input if it starts with a zero. I think the answer from chepner/jackman is more concise.

Comment: You have to check your input anyway, right? you're not just using user input without checking anything, right? so why not use a regex like `if [[ $input =~ ^0*([[:digit:]]*)$ ]]; then input=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; printf '%04d\n' "$input"; else echo 'bad input'; fi`.

Comment: @Barmar gave me the idea for `while echo "$input"|grep -q '^0';do input=$(echo "$input"|cut -c2-);done`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prefix the value with a base specifier of `10#`.

```
$ printf "%04d\n" "$input"
0009
$ printf "%04d\n" "$((10#$input))"
0011
```

Comment: Need to use arithmetic evaluation there

Comment: Thanks; I overlooked the error message I got, and `printf` produces output for `10` (after dropping the `#011`) anyway.